# JdbcSQLException executing PostgreSQL query with 'MATCH simple' in H2

Tags: spring, postgresql, h2

I'm trying to run in development mode (with H2) a setup currently used in production with a PostgreSQL database and I get an error. It would be best if I could reuse the production SQL without any change to it.

Using this setup:

```
# H2 Database
spring.datasource.datasource-class-name=org.h2.jdbcx.JdbcDataSource
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:userregistry;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;MODE=PostgreSQL
```

This query:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users.user_userrole (
    user_signum VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    role VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT user_userrole_pk PRIMARY KEY (user_signum, role),
    CONSTRAINT user_fk FOREIGN KEY (user_signum) REFERENCES users.user (signum) MATCH SIMPLE,
    CONSTRAINT role_fk FOREIGN KEY (role) REFERENCES users.userrole   
  (role_name) MATCH SIMPLE
);
```

Raises this exception:

```
org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Syntax error in SQL statement "<<SQL OMITTED FOR BREVITY>>"; 
expected "INDEX, ON, NOT, DEFERRABLE, NOCHECK, CHECK, ,, )";  [42001-185]
```

Note that I am already using `Mode=PostgreSQL`. Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Another good example why it's a bad idea to use a different DBMS for production and testing. The only way to "reuse" production SQL without changes is to install Postgres locally.

Comment: Whats the point of using 2 different DB's in prod and test. It doesn't let you explore the kinks a DB has, which you will find in test and fix the code to use in Production. If you just change the DB, not only you are wasting your efforts to fix problems to work with test DB, but also shooting yourself in the foot afterwards by changing the DB completely as your efforts are useless at that time.

Comment: Having a dev in-memory database and a "regular" prod database is an extended practice. Specially if you later use technologies such as JPA (like in this case, which is a really simple CRUD business logic) that isolates your code from the DBMS. This is OK as far as you don´t write native SQL (which is legacy and I can´t change). There lies the problem.

Comment: Are you sure that it is the query you refer in this question? 'cause according to the error message, you have somewhere the string literal "<<SQL OMITTED FOR BREVITY>>" in one of your queries. Try to replace <<SQL OMITTED FOR BREVITY>> with /* SQL OMMITTED FOR BREVITY */

Comment: Yes I wrote that literal in order not to make the question too long too read :-)

Comment: You can see the actual query in the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The H2 database does not support `MATCH SIMPLE` (same as Oracle, MS SQL Server, Apache Derby).

Comment: Hi Thomas, thanks for the answer. You are right 'MATCH SIMPLE' was not supported. I wonder if there is any document describing the limitations of H2 handling PostgreSQL features?

Comment: I'm sorry there is no such document.

Comment: is there any alternative for MATCH SIMPLE in ms sql server?

Comment: @SudoPehpeh my recommendation is to ask a new question with the appropriate tags.